# How many ways are there to choose an arbitrary number of students (including the possibility of choosing 0 students) from 6 students?

Tags: combinatorics, factorial

I'm a little confused by the wording of this question, more specifically "an arbitrary number".

Is the answer to this 6!? Or simply 7?

Thanks!

Comment: In this question, it means $$\#(\text{ways of choosing } 0 \text{ students from } 6 \text{ students}) + \#(\text{ways of choosing } 1 \text{ students from } 6 \text{ students}) + \#(\text{ways of choosing } 2 \text{ students from } 6 \text{ students}) + \dots + \#(\text{ways of choosing } 6 \text{ students from } 6 \text{ students})$$

Comment: remember that people are, for lack of better word, distinct or distinguishable.

Comment: Ah, so would the solution be 6C0 + 6C1 + 6C2 + ... + 6C6?

Comment: That's right, you've got it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add to the answers in the comments note that if the set of students is given by $S = \{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$ then the question similarly asks what is the number of subsets of $S$. From the definition of the power set we know this to be $2^{|S|}$.

This is also a neat combinatorial argument for why
$$2^n = \sum_{i=0}^n {n \choose i}.$$
An alternative way of proving this formula is with the [Binomial Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem) by choosing $x=y=1$.